# Column aligning does not work when using kableExtra linebreak

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

Creating a latex table using `kbl` and `linebreak` results in a weird alignement of the text column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(kableExtra)

data.frame(
  text = c(
    "Some longer line",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2"
    )
) %>%
mutate_all(linebreak) %>% 
kbl(booktabs = T, escape = F, format = "latex")
```

[image: result tabl]

How do I get the column left-aligned as expected?

Answer (score 3):

Setting the `align` parameter in `linebreak` solves the problem.

```
data.frame(
  text = c(
    "Some longer line",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2",
    "Line 1\nLine 2"
    )
) %>%
mutate_all(linebreak, align = 'l') %>% 
kbl(booktabs = T, escape = F, format = "latex")
```